# Escaping bash variables to avoid privilege escalation

Tags: linux, bash, security, daemon

No this is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040216/escaping-bash-variable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810591/escaping-bash-variables-for-regular-expression-containing-double-quote-parenthe). I have a more specific problem.

## The situation

I have a root bash daemon that makes symlinks of files in a directory. It gets the filename of every file and makes a symlink of it. The problem arises when web-users can upload files to a folder where the files in it needs to be symlinked (yes this needs to be done, don't post an answer like: "you shouldn't"). My concern is that users can get root privilege when they craft a filename in such a way that they can 'escape' the symlink command and execute code as root.

## My question

Is it indeed possible to craft such a malicious payload in a filename (with limits of allowed characters in a linux file name system) to get root escalation?

Comment: That depends on how you are calling `ln`, but `ln "$fname"` should  be safe. You aren't using `eval`, so nothing in the value of `fname` is going to be treated as code. The only issue I can think of is a potential buffer overflow if `fname` is extremely long, but I think the risk there is minimal to non-existent.

Comment: We **hope** you are not using `eval`... And [you **must** properly quote all variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667).

Comment: Any way, you could add some extra check in the daemon to make sure that the filename doesn't hide any malicious command before creating the symlink

Comment: This fully answers my question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it indeed possible to craft such a malicious payload in a filename [...] to get a root escalation?

The first step is to run an arbitrary command; getting a root escalation is then a question of exploiting separate privilege escalation bugs in the local system, which is a bit out-of-scope for a question about bash.

In terms of whether one can run an arbitrary command by data passed to a shell script: Not if the shell script is written correctly. If it has arbitrary, and potentially buggy, contents, then perhaps so. Without seeing a specific script to audit, how are we to say?

---

> My concern is that users can get root privilege when they craft a filename in such a way that they can 'escape' the symlink command and execute code as root.

This isn't possible if your script is correctly written.

Use `--` to prevent names from being treated as options, and double-quotes to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion.

```
ln -- "$source" "$dest"
```

Arguments such as `-s` and `-f` must go **before** the `--`, which asserts that all following arguments are interpreted as positional.

Other parts of the script are also relevant: If you're parsing `ls`, using `eval`, or performing `eval`-equivalent operations (such as expanding user-controlled variables in strings which are treated as scripts; `ssh` arguments are an example of such; so are unquoted heredocs performing expansions), these can introduce vulnerabilities.

---

Which is to say: There are numerous things that can be done right (or wrong), and we'd need to see your code to audit it. Not that StackOverflow is the right place for that -- perhaps the Code Review StackExchange site? Be sure to run contents through http://shellcheck.net/ before submitting them for human review as well.